# Janus 2 GridEx disable a Button in a given cell

Tags: janus, gridex

There isn't much support with Janus, thats why i'm asking you for help.
I have a gridEx with 3 columns(INT ID, String MARKET, Button DELETE). when you add an item to the grid you only have to add the ID and MARKET, the button DELETE is automatically created and enabled.

What i want is for the element with ID=5 the button of that row must be disabled.
the data of the gridEx  has a DataSource but is only binded with ID and MARKET.
the Data configuration of the GridEx Designer of the cell button DELETE the Bound is False and it hasn't got any DataMember.

What i have is the element wiht ID=5 but i don't know how to programatically disable the cell Button of that element in the grid.

Any clue of how to accomplish this issue???

Thanks!!

Comment: Please show code from your attempt

Answer (score 0):

You have to utilize the FormattingRow event of the grid.

This is a sample code:

```
    private void grdex_FormattingRow(object sender, RowLoadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowType.Record)
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells["ID"].Value) == 5)
                e.Row.Cells["DELETE"].ButtonEnabled = false;

    }
```